# Why does the Talmud use the term רחמנא?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, talmud-bavli

When quoting verses, the Talmud often says something like אמר רחמנא - "the Merciful One said..."

What is the significance of this name? Why not use a name like הקדוש ברוך הוא - a name commonly found in the Talmud? What does God's mercy have to do with writing something in the Torah?

Comment: Hakadosh Baruch Hu, in fact, is the name the Midrash Rabbah very rarely fails to use when discussing Hashem. I had heard a pshat in why the Gemara prefers Rachmana, besides for @GershonGold's pshat, but I don't remember it.

Answer (score 4):

[Mishna Berura 167:51](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=123) says that the word רחמנא in Hashems name in Lashon Bavli. I would imagine that since the Talmud Bavli was not written in Hebrew they used the name of Hashem which was popular in the then current day vernacular.

Comment: But they also use Hakadosh Baruch Hu sometimes. Why by Pesukim do they use Rachmana? I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Is it an actual foreign term or a Jewish term? Is there any historical data about a word like this?

Answer (score 4):

There is a claim made here
 http://books.google.com/books?id=mIqrXP1QRwgC&pg=PA369&lpg=PA369&dq=babylonian+rachmana&source=bl&ots=Yu0uJuK4qK&sig=nOJFjCzDrrz8mE8m_5CvWYRMsMo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=g2RiVOOSA-nksAScqoLoAw&ved=0CCwQ6AEwBg

In the Babylonian Talmud, as I have elsewhere pointed out", one of the most frequent appellatives of God is the “merciful one” (Rachmana), and it is worth noticing that this term is mostly used in Halachic or casuistic discussions
1 '1 ‘man rm: (ed. Sluzki, p.45). 2 JEWISH QUARTERLY REVIEW, VI, 422.
about ritual cases, which proves how little in the mind of the Rabbis the Law was connected with hardness and chastisement. To them it was an effluence of God’s mercy and goodness. In the daily prayer of the Jews the same sentiment is expressed in most glowing words: “With everlasting love thou hast loved the house of Israel, thy people; Torah, commandments, statutes, and judgments hast thou taught us. . . . Yea, we will rejoice in the words of thy Torah and thy commandments for ever. . . . And mayest thou never take away thy love from us. Blessed art thou, O Lord, who lovest thy people Israel.”